# Unable to review Thingsboard gateway statistics installed as python module

Tags: python, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I'm trying to install the `Thingsboard` gateway in TechBase controller devices. I'm following the Thingsboard documentation available at [1](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/getting-started/), [2](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/install/pip-installation/), and [3](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/configuration/). I've attempted to install the gateway as a python module. The installation process goes fine and I'm able to edit the `/etc/thingsboard-gateway/config/tb_gateway.yaml` file with my `host`, `port`, and `accessToken`. After using the `systemctl restart thingsboard-gateway.service` command, the thingsboard-gateway gets restarted. However, I'm unable to see anything in the `Latest Telemetry` tab at my gateway device.

A strange line is written in the documentation as follows (which makes no sense at all):

**`if you have installed the gateway as python module - you should just rerun gateway process.`**

Am I missing something mentioned in the above line? Any solutions, please!

**UPDATE:** After a further search, I guess that `to rerun the gateway process` means the following:

```
sudo python3 -c 'from thingsboard_gateway.gateway.tb_gateway_service import TBGatewayService; TBGatewayService("./tb_gateway.yaml")'
```

I get the following after running the above line:

[image]

When I run `thingsboard-gateway` command, I get an error as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]